# From record schema to map schema in Clojure

Tags: clojure, schema, record

When I have a record with a schema defined as follows:

```
(schema.core/defrecord Account [id :- schema/Uuid
                                short-id :- schema/Str
                                name :- schema/Str
                                created-at :- schema/Inst])
```

How do I extract the schema to apply to a hashmap that will contain those values?

The reason is that the HTTP service receives maps and automatically applies schemas to them and if I just use Account it fails because the map is not of Account type.

I tried to extract from explain, as in:

```
(schema.core/explain Account)
```

but what I get is not really a schema:

```
{:id Uuid,
 :short-id Str,
 :name Str,
 :created-at Inst}
```

The values are symbols instead of classes, so, if you try to use it:

```
(schema.core/validate (last (schema.core/explain server.models.account.Account)) {})
```

you get this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException No implementation of method: :spec of protocol: #'schema.core/Schema found for class: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:568)
```

Comment: You are asking how to extract this schema from a record definition, or how to construct an equivalent schema for a map?

Comment: @fl00r how to extract it from the record, so that I don't have to manually re-create it. I'll amend the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a built-in `explain` function:

```
(last (schema.core/explain Account))
{:id Uuid, :short-id Str, :name Str, :created-at Inst}
```

Or little more tricky `spec`

```
(-> (schema.core/spec Account) 
    :options
    first 
    :schema 
    last 
    last)
{:id java.util.UUID, :short-id java.lang.String, :name java.lang.String, :created-at java.util.Date}
```

Comment: The first one is not a valid schema. Str there is a symbol instead of schema.core/Str, that is a class.

Comment: The solution getting it from the spec seems to work, but it is indeed convoluted.